# Sync enviroments JPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa, synchronization

I would like to know how can I Sync beta enviromet with the values of the Production DB. All the database is modeled with JPA and I want to "move" the values from the prod DB to beta

I have look in the internet but I can't find a solution and I can imagine that this shoud be easy

Comment: Have you searched for exporting a database dump from your production database, then importing that dump into your beta environment database ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.